# Missing Certificates Tab when viewing properties of a VM role in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, azure, dns

I've been trying to connect my Azure VM role to my domain and was following the steps provided by the Windows Connect Azure team blog as shown here: . However, I hit a snag when I was asked to click on the certificates Tab and create a certificate. Wonder of wonders, there is no Certificates tab that appears on the properties of the VM role properties page. All I see are the following tabs: Virtal Hard Disk, Configuration, Settings, Endpoints and Virtual Network. Any clue as to wjhat I might be doing wrong? I will appreciate any help greatly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the tutorial you are following is for a web or worker roles?

If you're creating a Virtual Machine role, then I don't think you can specify the certificates to install. If you want to pre-install certificates, then you can do this yourself within the VM image?